# Difference between several "Fail" usages

Tags: difference, usage

I want to say something did not fail:

1. The task finished with no fail
2. The task finished without fail
3. The task finished with no failure
4. The task finished without failure
5. The task finished with none failed

is there any difference and if any is incorrect?
Thank you

Comment: Can you give a complete example sentence where you want to use this phrase?

Comment: @ThePhoton Yup, updated

Answer (score 1):

Either 3 or 4 is acceptable. I'd be more likely to use the plural, "The task finished with no failures".

Number 5 might be acceptable if there is context to establish what the *none* refers to.

"Without fail" is an idiom that means "ceratainly" and is usually used to refer to future events. For example, "I'll be at your party on Friday without fail".

"No fail(*)" isn't used because "fail" is a verb (except in the idiom "without fail") so we can't use *no* with it.

Comment: Thank you, but "fail" can also be a noun, as in grading?